# Regular expersion repeat inside a pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have the following text and I would like to `preg_match_all` what is within the `{`'s and `}`'s if it contains only `a-zA-Z0-9` and `:`

```
some text,{SOMETHING21} {SOMETHI32NG:MORE}some msdf{TEXT:GET:2}sdfssdf sdf sdf
```

I am trying to match `{SOMETHING21}` `{SOMETHI32NG:MORE}` `{TEXT:GET:2}` there can be several `:`'s within the tag.

What I currently have is:

```
preg_match_all('/\{([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)(\:([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+))*\}/', $from, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

It works as expected for `{SOMETHING21}` and `{SOMETHI32NG:MORE}` but for `{TEXT:GET:2}` it only matches `TEXT` and `2`

So it only matches the first and last word within the tag, and leaves the middle ones out of the `$matches` array. Is this even possible or should I just match them and then explode on `:` ?

-- edit --

Well the question isn't if I can get the tags, the question is if I can get them grouped without having to explode the results again. Even though my current regex finds all the results the subpattern does not come back with all the matches in `$matches`.

I hope the following will clear it up abit more:

```
\{                              // the match has to start with {
([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)                // after the { the match needs to have alphanum consisting out of 1 or more characters
(
    \:                          // if we have : it should be followed by alphanum consisting out of 1 or more characters
    ([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)            // <---- !! this is what it is about !! even though this subexpression is between brackets it is not put into $matches if more then one of these is found
)*                              // there could be none or more of the previous subexpression
\}                              // the match has to end with }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get all the matched values of a capturing group, you only get the last one.

So you have to match the pattern:

```
preg_match_all('/{([a-z\d-]+(?::[a-z\d-]+)*)}/i', $from, $matches);
```

and then split each element in `$matches[1]` on `:`.

Comment: Need to escape the `{` curly brace. Otherwise +1

Comment: @ridgerunner, you don't need to escape `{` in this case.

Comment: I was hoping I could do this without having to explode my `$matches[1]`. Anyway, thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: @jeffreydev, .NET regex is the only flavor that you could do that with. But if you have a known limited number of `:` you could use optional capturing groups if you want.

Answer (score 1):

I used non-capture groupings to eliminate the inner groups, and just capture the outer complete colon-separated list.

```
$from = "some text,{SOMETHING21} {SOMETHI32NG:MORE}some msdf{TEXT:GET:2}sdfssdf sdf sdf";
preg_match_all('/\{((?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)(?:\:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+))*)\}/', $from, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($matches);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => {SOMETHING21}
        [1] => SOMETHING21
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => {SOMETHI32NG:MORE}
        [1] => SOMETHI32NG:MORE
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => {TEXT:GET:2}
        [1] => TEXT:GET:2
    )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn't understand the requirement, but...

```
preg_match_all('/{[A-Za-z0-9:-]+}/', $from, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {SOMETHING21}
            [1] => {SOMETHI32NG:MORE}
            [2] => {TEXT:GET:2}
        )
)
```